# Is there a proper way to use the Appcompat "NavigationView" as permanent (see Material Design guidelines)

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview, android-navigationview

By reading the Material Design guidelines about the Navigation Drawer (Drawerlayout + NavigationView) I see there is a recommandation to set it always opened on desktop. That's what I would like to achieve on tablets.

> Permanent navigation drawers are always visible and pinned to the left
>   edge, at the same elevation as the content or background. They cannot
>   be closed.

[image]

But it seems that the widget offered in support library is not easy to manipulate and achieve such an effect.

Did I missed something, or is there an easy way to let it opened on tablets/desktop/TV?

My current phone layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primarycolor"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>


<!-- The navigation drawer   style="@style/NavDrawer"

                 android:background="@android:color/white"-->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/nav" />
```

Comment: Are you looking for lockMode? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerLockMode(int, int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use navigation view as a drawer do not put the `NavigationView` directly inside the `DrawerLayout`.

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <NavigationView android:layout_width="320dp" />
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
            <Toolbar/>
            <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</DrawerLayout>
```

Put this layout inside `/res/layout-sw600dp-land`. Your original layout will be loaded on phones and this one on 7" tablets and above in landscape.

Comment: OMG, this is so simple, why did I missed that?

Comment: Note: I completely removed the DrawerLayout, is there any reason to keep it?

Comment: Only if you wanted to use the right drawer for something.

Comment: Only issue I saw is the focus that go crazy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992356/permanent-navigationview-loose-focus-after-an-item-is-selected

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DevrimTuncer answer, I have found this post: http://derekrwoods.com/2013/09/creating-a-static-navigation-drawer-in-android/

In addition to:

```
 drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN, drawerList);
```

We must also set:

```
drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

And add some margins:

values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="drawer_size">240dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="drawer_content_padding">0dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-sw720dp-land/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="drawer_content_padding">240dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a boolean resource value and use it to set drawer lock mode for this. For instance:

```
res
  -- values
    -- drawer_layout_values.xml
         <bool name="drawer_layout_locked">false</bool>
  -- values-sw720dp
    -- drawer_layout_values.xml
         <bool name="drawer_layout_locked">true</bool>
```

Code:

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.drawer_layout_locked)) {
    drawerLayoutInstance.setDrawerLockMode (DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN)
}
```