# Permanent NavigationView loose focus after an item is selected

Tags: android, focus, navigation-drawer

I started a project with a Navigation Drawer from the basic template of Android Studio. The only modification I made was to display it as permanent in order to have a tablet/TV layout.

To achieve this, the only modification I made was in the xml layout. This allow the NavigationView to be always visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Content will come here" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also put the project on Github, so anyone can test it.

**PROJECT DEMO ON GITHUB**

https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/NavFocus

**WHAT IS HAPPENING**

My issue comes when I start selecting items on the drawer with the D-pad.
Once an item is selected, the focus is completely lost. Trying to get back to the Drawer and get focus seems very hard and I have to try several times with right/left arrows

**WHAT IS EXPECTED:**

Drawer should keep focus, or focus should be easy to bring back to the Drawer.

**WHAT I TRIED:**

The simplest Idea I had was to force the Drawer to get focus again, but this code doesn't change anything:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    //This is where I will replace the Fragments in the right area.
                    navigationView.clearFocus();
                    navigationView.requestFocus();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: will it possible for you to upload images for what is expected and what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by removing `android:layout_gravity="start"`
This is simply not needed as its parent is a horizontal LinearLayout.

The Navigation Drawer must be permanently visible on Tablets and TV. They stay hidden for mobile. These are part of the Material Design [guidelines](https://material.google.com/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior).

This requires quite a different setup compared to what I see in your project on GitHub. Which includes supplying different resources using qualifiers.

[This tutorial on Navigation Drawer (Design Support)](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/material-design-for-tablets/) will help you with exactly that setup, as per the latest Material Design guidelines. Alternatively the project files for the tutorial can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Suleiman19/Material-Design-Tablet-App).

**UPDATE:**
As pointed out, Support library v24 creates issues with the dpad. Reverting to v23 works just fine.

Comment: Hello, your demo app is working and I updated my project with your code, but the issue is still happening on mine. I suspect other configuration issue rather than just layout/Java code... Still investigation! https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/NavFocus

Comment: Update your code to use support v24 and it will break the NavigationView behavior with d-pad.

Comment: But you desrved to getthe bounty, please update your answer or post another one, I will delete mine and accept yours, you deserve it.

Comment: That's sweet. Also, please raise this issue if it hasn't been done already: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list
Thanks

Comment: This was done 6 days ago ;-) I added today a comment to clarify that v23 works fine, but I doubt it will get much attention there: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220205&thanks=220205&ts=1471443911